# Java Memory Leak with Scanner on Akka

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, akka

[image]

The orange color is the "OldGen", Green is "Eden Space", and blue is "survivor space". I used YourKit to do this profiling. This is how I wrote my file reading code:

```
val inputStream = new FileInputStream("E:\\Allen\\DataScience\\train\\train.csv")
val sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8")

var counter = 0

while (sc.hasNextLine) {

  rowActors(counter % 20) ! Row(sc.nextLine())

  counter += 1
}

sc.close()
inputStream.close()
```

It seems like a big chunk of memory if taken by Scanner. However, my original file is only 5 GB large. I wonder if I was mishandling the file reading procedure! If not, how should I read in and process my file? I'm very frustrated with the Garbage Collection right now.

Comment: (1) I don't see any memory leak. Seems like both generations are stable. Not sure what you are talking about. (2) The object sizes yourkit shows are not additive (if there are 100 references to a string, it's size is counted 100 times). (3) Your young gen seems to be too small for scala. Increases it. (4) Why are you using `Scanner` in scala? Seems backwards. Just do `for(line <- Source.fromFile("filename").getLines) { ... }`

Comment: @Dima The Non-heap memory is very stable, but the heap memory was growing from 500mb to 15gb (reaching to the limit I set). Shouldn't this be counted as memory-leak? OK..I was comparing the difference between `bufferedReader` and "Source.fromFile"...and try to know which one is more efficient since my file has 40 million lines.

Comment: So, you are creating 40 million `Rows` in memory at once? 15GB is about 375 bytes per `Row`. Seems rather small. A memory leak is when you have memory allocated, that is not used. In your case this is not what happened. Your memory is all used. Just badly :)

Comment: @Dima I see! That's very helpful! Is there a way to improve my memory usage so I don't go over the limit?

Comment: Well, that depends in what your actors are doing. I don't know akka, but in general the approach is a fixed number of consumers and a  limited size queue, blocking on overflow on the producer side, so that there are only so many objects in memory at any given time. That's assuming that the actors produce result, and write it somewhere, of course. If the results are all kept in memory,  you'd have to start with rethinking that approach.

Comment: @Dima Thank you. I'll either go back to Java's threads or wait for someone that can explain how I can make this work!

Comment: There's gotta be some akka config that let's you limit the queue size. You don't have to "go back to java threads" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akka-stream provides safer way for parallel processing of files: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-akka-stream-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/sample/stream/GroupLogFile.scala

Comment: Yes. I asked this question on Mail list and they gave me this answer. Thank you still, btw.